# Application deployment mechanism types of Spring applications

Tags: java, spring, deployment, jvm

I am implementing an application in order to run multiple spring applicationcontext files which are different from each other(acts totally different). We can say that they are actually different applications. But the question is that the way I will deploy.

I certainly can make different jar files and create a seperate JVM at runtime but I can also create AbstractApplicationContext instances in one jvm and manage them in one pot.

I chose the second one because of efficient resource sharing(memory). My question is, is it a wrong way to do it? Will there any fatal problems ahead?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you run the three applications in one JVM, you must always use the same version of java and libraries for all three, which may be a problem if you need to upgrade for one app but cant for another.
If any of the underlying libraries uses singletons, all three apps will share them, which might also lead to problems.

So I would suggest to keep them seperated.